# Redshift: Does key-based distribution optimize equality filters?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

[This](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_choosing_dist_sort.html) documentation describes key-distribution in redshift as follows:

> The rows are distributed according to the values in one column. The
>   leader node will attempt to place matching values on the same node
>   slice. If you distribute a pair of tables on the joining keys, the
>   leader node collocates the rows on the slices according to the values
>   in the joining columns so that matching values from the common columns
>   are physically stored together.

I was wondering if key-distribution additionally helps in optimizing equality filters. My intuition says it should but it isn't mentioned anywhere.

Also, I saw a [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/tutorial-tuning-tables-sort-keys.html) regarding sort-keys which says that to select a sort-key:

> Look for columns that are used in range filters and **equality** filters.

This got me confused since sort-keys are explicitly mentioned as a way to optimize equality filters.

I am asking this because I already have a candidate sort-key on which I will be doing range queries. But I also want to have quick equality filters on another column which is a good distribution key in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a very bad idea to be filtering on a distribution key, especially if your table / cluster is large.

The reason is that the filter may be running on just one slice, in effect running without the benefit of MPP.

For example, if you have a dist key of "added_date", you may find that all of the added date for the previous week are all together on one slice.

You will then have the majority of queries filtering for recent ranges of added_date, and these queries will be concentrated and will saturate that one slice.

Comment: Any suggestions for choosing dist-key/sort-key for my use-case?

Comment: I think you are on the right track - with redshift you cannot meet all use cases with your sort keys - just make sure your data is distributed well - try it out.

Comment: what about an interleaved sort-key? i'll have column A as a dist-key and column A + column B as an interleaved sort-key. won't this solve the problem?

Comment: partly - you still have the problem with the dist key - and there are pros and cons of interleaved sort keys. maybe if you update your question with more detail?

Comment: Avoid using Interleaved sort keys -- they have a VERY large overhead during VACUUMs and are only beneficial in a few specific situations.

Comment: If there was a date field, values for different dates would be hashed to different slices. The dates that fall in a given week would be distributed, rather than all being on one node. Date fields are normally used for SORTKEY, not DISTKEY.

Answer (score 1):

The simple rule is:

- Use DISTKEY for the column most commonly joined
- Use SORTKEY for fields most commonly used in a WHERE statement

There actually are benefits to using the same field for SORTKEY and DISTKEY. From [Choose the Best Sort Key](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-sort-key.html):

> **If you frequently join a table, specify the join column as both the sort key and the distribution key.**
>
> This enables the query optimizer to choose a sort merge join instead of a slower hash join. Because the data is already sorted on the join key, the query optimizer can bypass the sort phase of the sort merge join.

Feel free to do some performance tests -- create a few different versions of the table, and use INSERT or SELECT INTO to populate them. Then, try common queries to see how they perform.

Comment: John, when would you recommend "same field for SORTKEY and DISTKEY"

Comment: Updated answer with a reference.

Comment: why can't we use DISTKEY for equality filters as well? DISTKEY would help me identify the slice in which the data is present. Isn't that a good enough optimization (even if we can't leverage MPP)?

Comment: If you use a WHERE clause to identify a **single value** in a column, and the column is the DISTKEY, it means that only one slice is participating in the query. The power of Redshift comes from parallelizing queries, so it is best to use multiple slices simultaneously.